# stripe not able to add bank account in test mode

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have created stripe account, which is in test mode, I want to do payout functionality, so i want to add bank account in it, but when i add bank account, It always says me `Known test bank accounts cannot be used in live mode.`, I am using Account Number  : `000123456789` and Rounting Number :  `110000000` , why i am getting this message ?  can anyone please help me ?

I did some googling but it doesn't help me. Can anyone please help me how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely using [Standard accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) and trying to provide a test bank account in the OAuth form.

Even if you're in test mode, it is not possible to provide fake information in the OAuth form, as the account that would be created is a real account that might be used in live mode later. Instead, if you're using your platform's development client_id, you should use the "Skip this form" link at the top of the OAuth form.

Unfortunately, that means it is not possible to test payouts with Standard accounts without providing real bank account information. In practice though, there's little need to test this feature: with Standard accounts, the platform does not have control over payouts, and the account's owner will directly set their payout settings in their dashboard.

Comment: Can you provide any detail about how to ensure I'm using my platform's development client_id? I'm hitting the same problem but don't see the "skip this form" link.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. I was using the generated link to manually add a connected account, generated using the "create" button of the "managed accounts" view. But I did not have "View test data" toggled on. Fixing this generated the proper link.